# IIS site will not load

Tags: php, windows, iis, admin, iis-10

I am running a site on my home computer with IIS 10.0. I have already set the permissions to full-control (more specifically, I set IIS_IUSRS to Full control).
However, when I run the site (by right-clicking it and hitting Manage Website --> Browse), I get an empty loading page. It keeps loading and never finishes, and doesn't show any errors. My site is very simple (basically a hello world site).

My site is made with php. I have tried these URLs: localhost, localhost:80 (the port number), localhost/index.php, and localhost:80/index.php. None of them work.

I also have another php site that I hosted with IIS 10.0 and it works.

Why does this happen? How do I fix it?

Some more details:
Anonymous Authentication is enabled and set to Application pool identity
ASP.NET Impersonation is disabled
The site has a config file

Comment: This is a question about server administration, not programming. You can ask this question on [Server Fault](//serverfault.com)

Comment: Make sure your PHP environment is set up, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/php-diagnostics.html

Comment: it is set up. I have another php site on the computer, hosted with IIS, that works

Comment: I suggest you could firstly use F12 develop tool's to find if there is any error in the console. Then I suggest you could try to use F12 develop tool's network tag to find out which resource is keeping loading. As far as I know, if the request is exceed 30 seconds, the IIS will directly return time-out issue.